# How to apply multiply blend mode in canvas for specific drawn object to get mix blend mode effect

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a scenario, one canvas with 4 objects:

1. Top     = a white t shirt
2. Middle  = Hello text and floral artwork
3. Bottom  = Red t shirt

I want to apply multiply effect on Top t-shirt, I am using:

```
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'multiply';
```

but it applies to all objects. Please check **[my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/itzasifmirza/8nueaqfy/)**.

On top left the css effect and in bottom canvas effect, I want canvas effect as css effect.

In css I have achieved this with mix-blend-mode multiply. As you can see in fiddle floral artwork's white color is not showing in canvas it's because multiply applied to all object i don't know why.

If you have any better solution let me know.
Regards.

Comment: some resources in the fiddle link requires authentication is seems

Comment: @Asif Agreeing with K3N. In fact, your link hung my browser for a minute, so please repost a more appropriate link.

Comment: sorry for that, please check now https://jsfiddle.net/itzasifmirza/8nueaqfy/
please open in google chrome.